# MySQL Conditioning Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I was trying with writing a query to select a row from the table (attached screenshot). This is something peculiar, where `*` means any value. I need to select a row where `Amount` should be between Start Amount and End Amount and Department should be IT.

The condition for `Country` and `Sub Department` is a bit tricky. If the selected country is not in the `Country` column then the query should return me the record with `*` and same is the case with sub department.

[image]

I tried with a approach of selecting columns based on Department and amount like this

```
Select * from table_name where Department = 'IT' 
and 1000 BETWEEN Start Amount AND End Amount
```

But, after this I am not sure how to get the result with below condition.

If country is not India then all `*` results I should get.

Comment: Instead of picture, just create a fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want something like:

```
  SELECT * 
    FROM table_name 
   WHERE Department = 'IT' 
     AND 1000 BETWEEN `Start Amount` AND `End Amount`
     AND country IN ('India','*')
     AND `Sub Department` IN ('SD2','*')
ORDER BY country = 'India' DESC,
         `Sub Department` = 'SD2' DESC
   LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But for the first time I've seen something like passing country = 'India' in group by clause.What purpose it will serve??

Comment: @Hitesh Well it's an ORDER BY, but basically a condition evaluates to 1 (true), 0 (false) or null (removed by your where logic). Thus by using DESC, rows that evaluate true return earlier. N.B. this will only ever return 1 row, if you need something more, look at FuzzyTree's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use a union all to assign a group number in order of preference to every permitted combination of country/sub_department i.e. `(India,SD1) (India,*) (*,*)` then only select the rows with the lowest group number.

```
select t1.* from (
    Select t1.* ,
    if(@minGroup > groupNumber, @minGroup := groupNumber, @minGroup) minGroupNumber
    from (
        Select t1.*, 1 groupNumber from table_name t1
        where Department = 'IT' 
        and 1000 BETWEEN `Start Amount` AND `End Amount`
        and country = 'India'
        and sub_department = 'SD1'

        union all

        Select t1.*, 2 groupNumber from table_name t1
        where Department = 'IT' 
        and 1000 BETWEEN `Start Amount` AND `End Amount`
        and country = 'India'
        and sub_department = '*'

        union all

        Select t1.*, 3 groupNumber from table_name t1
        where Department = 'IT' 
        and 1000 BETWEEN `Start Amount` AND `End Amount`
        and country = '*'
        and sub_department = '*'
    ) t1 cross join (select @minGroup := 3) t2
) t1 where groupNumber = @minGroup
```

Comment: Love the group logic.. I have a feeling this is more like what the OP is after.

Answer (score 0):

Re-sending bcz, star is truncated

Select  NVL(tc.Country, '*') Country_Column_name,
        NVL(tsd.Sub_Dept, '*') Sub_Dept_Column_name
from    table_name tn
LEFT OUTER JOIN table_country tc
ON      tn.Country = tc.Country
LEFT OUTER JOIN table_sub_dept tsd
ON      tn.Sub Dept = tsd.Sub Dept
where   Department = 'IT' 
and     1000 BETWEEN Start Amount AND End Amount

Note: Country & Sub Dpt table should have unique column and that should be used in the join.